# Running a module from a library in dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, python-poetry

At the begging when creating this project I had a certain file under the following path  my_app/my_app/my_file.py . The contents of that file are needed to create the docs.

My Dockerfile at the time looked like:

```
RUN . /opt/.venv/bin/activate && python -m my_app.my_file
```

After that I created a new library, a part of which is that file. That library gets installed with poetry into my project.

I'd like to do sth similar to what was done before.

so this is the excerpt from my current Dockerfile:

```
RUN . /opt/.venv/bin/activate && python -m my_library.my_file
```

When I do pip list in my container I can see my-library listed there.

But the docs don't get generated anymore.
Is there another way to run a module from a library in the Dockerfile?

Comment: can you share how you are installing it and creating the environment ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
RUN /opt/.venv/bin/python -m my_library.my_file
```